# How to await all results from an IAsyncEnumerable<>?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

I'm tinkering around with the new `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` stuff in C# 8.0. Let's say I've got some method somewhere that I want to consume:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<T> SomeBlackBoxFunctionAsync<T>(...) { ... }
```

I'm aware that I can use it with the `await foreach...` syntax. But let's say my consumer needs to have *all* results from this function before it continues. What's the best syntax to await all results before continuing? In other words, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
// but that extension - AllResultsAsync() - doesn't exist :-/
List<T> myList = await SomeBlackBoxFunctionAsync<T>().AllResultsAsync();
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Task.WaitAll() ??

Comment: @AzharKhorasany What would that syntax look like? I've tinkered with `Task.WhenAll()`, but I can't get that to work.

Comment: `await foreach (var item in SomeBlackBoxFunctionAsync<T>()) myList.Add(item);`

Comment: Return Task from your method and then WaitAll.

Comment: Why do you want to consume the entire stream before processing the results? By definition, an async stream may never end

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A warning first: by definition, an async stream **may never end** and keep producing results until the application terminates. This is *already* used e.g. in SignalR or gRPC. Polling loops also work this way.

As such, using `ToListAsync` on an async stream may have unintended consequences!

---

Operators like this are already available through the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package.

Consuming the entire stream is available through [ToListAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToList.cs). The code is *deceptively* simple, but hides a few interesting issues :

```
public static ValueTask<List<TSource>> ToListAsync<TSource>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>? source, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (source is null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));

    if (source is IAsyncIListProvider<TSource> listProvider)
        return listProvider.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    return Core(source, cancellationToken);

    static async ValueTask<List<TSource>> Core(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var list = new List<TSource>();

        await foreach (var item in source.WithCancellation(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

First of all, it returns a `ValueTask`. Second, it ensures cancellation is observed and `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used, to prevent deadlocks. Finally, if the source already offers its own `ToListAsync` implementation via `IAsyncIListProvider`, the operator defers to that.

It's also interesting to note that while the `IAsyncIListProvider` interface is public, it's only implemented by internal and private classes within System.Linq.Async.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @DmitryBychenko's comment, I wrote an extension to do want I want:

```
    public static async Task<ICollection<T>> AllResultsAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable)
    {
        if (null == asyncEnumerable)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(asyncEnumerable));  

        var list = new List<T>();
        await foreach (var t in asyncEnumerable)
        {
            list.Add(t);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I'm just a little surprised this wasn't shipped natively with C# 8.0...it seems like a pretty obvious need.

Comment: Have a look at this GitHub [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36545), basically there a community based package and [repo](https://github.com/Damien-The-Unbeliever/Linq.AsyncEnumerable) with linq support for AsyncEnumerable. Or use `System.Linq.Async` provided by Rx.

Comment: Please, add *validation* (since `AllResultsAsync` is a `public` method) for `asyncEnumerable` - it must not be `null` and have my +1

Comment: It *is* shipped, as part of the System.Linq.Async package.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Happy to hear it! What's the method called in System.Linq.Async? If it's there, that should be the correct answer to my question.